# Populating form data from entity in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have an action that basically renders a form and I want it to be a new form if the ID is null and an edit form if the ID matches with the PK in the DB. Obviously my logic is wrong because a new form is rendering every single time. .

```
public function editGlobalFirewallFilter(Request $request, Entities\GlobalFirewallFilter $firewall_rule = null) {
n
    // Check if we have a valid rule. If not create a new blank one and associate our account id
    // if( ! $firewall_rule ) {
    //     $results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('bundle:GlobalFirewallFilter');
    //     $rules = $results->findAll();
    //     $firewall_rule = new Entities\GlobalFirewallFilter();
    // }
    $firewall_rule = new Entities\GlobalFirewallFilter();

    // Generate our form
    $form = $this->createForm(new SAForms\GlobalFirewallRuleType(), $firewall_rule);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {

        // Save our firewall rule
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($firewall_rule);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_dashboard__global_firewall'));
    }


        return array(
        'title'         => $firewall_rule->getFirewallFilterId() ? 'Edit Rule' : 'New Rule',
        'form'          => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `form generator command` to be oriented in the right way :

Generating a CRUD Controller Based on a Doctrine Entity

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html
use this command :

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

I will generate the skeleton of you controller with all the standard actions as wanted, in your specifica case, `updateAction`, `newAction`, and `editAction`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why are there `results`  and `rules` - you don't use them. I think this code should do the trick.

```
public function editGlobalFirewallFilter(Request $request, Entities\GlobalFirewallFilter $firewall_rule = null) {

    // Check if we have a valid rule. If not create a new blank one and associate our account id
    $firewall_rule = $firewall_rule ?: new Entities\GlobalFirewallFilter();

    // Generate our form
    $form = $this->createForm(new SAForms\GlobalFirewallRuleType(), $firewall_rule);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {

        // Save our firewall rule
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($firewall_rule);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_dashboard__global_firewall'));
    }


    return array(
        'title'         => $firewall_rule->getFirewallFilterId() ? 'Edit Rule' : 'New Rule',
        'form'          => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

---

P.S. Sadly I can't comment yet.. Can you provide controller actions where you use this function?